# Ввод с клавиатуры

Tags: ассемблер

Есть программа, которая из заданной строки удаляет заданный  символ. Как сделать так, чтобы эта строка и символ  вводились из клавиатуры? Заранее спасибо.

```
data segment
               string db 'CHTO TEBE NADO',0ah,'$' ; строка для обработки
               l    dw $ - string
data ends

code segment
assume cs:code,ds:data
start:
    mov ax,data
    mov ds,ax

    lea dx,string                      ;вывод на экран строки до обработки
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    mov dx,30h
    lea di,string
    mov cx,l
n:
    cmp byte ptr [di],'T'                    ;собственно здесь указан искомый символ.
    jne nn

;если найден искомый символ то перезапишем строку, без этого символа.
        mov si,di
        inc si
        push di
        push cx
        inc cx
        m:
            mov al,byte ptr [si]
            mov byte ptr [di],al
            inc si
            inc di
            loop m
            pop cx
            pop di
nn:
    inc di
    loop n

    lea dx,string                            ;вывод после обработки
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h
code ends
end start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вторая функция прерывания 21h читает символ с клавиатуры. Вам нужно организовать цикл на определенное количество чтений (или до ввода определенного символа).

```
mov ah, 2h
int 21h

; теперь в регистре al записан код символа, введенного пользователем
```